# Why can I not see some files in my USB stick on Windows that I can see on Linux?

Tags: usb-drive, storage, troubleshooting

I'm having a little problem with my USB stick. There are files and folders on the USB stick I can see and manipulate on my Linux machine (Fedora 20) but some of those files and folders appear nowhere when use the USB stick on a Windows machine. Moreover, according to Windows the USB stick has got almost 2.9 GB of files stored on it, but the files I can use amount to just 500+ MB. I don't know why this happens, but it's not the first time. What can I do to solve this problem permanently?

Comment: (1) What file system is the drive formatted with? (2) Can you show us a detailed listing of the drive from both Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 8):

### UPDATE

So, I really didn't think I would be researching `NTFS` this morning, but, thanks mostly to @AndrewMedico's comments below, I learned something.

The truth is file `streams` are weird, and they confuse me, but apparently it gets deeper. Behaving in a way very like `NTFS` file `streams`, `Transactional NTFS` commits file changes to some alternate cache until the change is guaranteed. When it is, the file is committed atomically and wholly in one piece. I confused the concept of the file `stream` - which I still believe must be a very fundamentally similar concept and likely involved in some way as there can be multiple `named` and only one `unnamed streams` for each file - with what is apparently happening with `TNTFS.` And I guess [I'm not the only one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS):

> Due to its complexity and various nuances which developers need to consider as part of application development, Microsoft is considering deprecating TxF APIs in a future version of Windows. Therefore, Microsoft strongly recommends developers investigate using the alternatives rather than adopting the **[`Transactional NTFS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** API platform which may not be available in future versions of Windows.

When I was putting together that Windows image I mentioned below, I had a problem with disappearing, reappearing files - seemingly even after deleting the disk entirely - which, amounted mostly truncating it actually. My theory then was - and still is in part - that the Linux cache was not committing the changes to the file `streams`. I think now instead that it just wasn't handling atomic commits in the way that was expected:

#### [Deleting a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> A file or directory that is deleted by calling the `DeleteFileTransacted` function **remains visible** to all outside readers.
>
> *Note  *All** transacted `handles` to the file must be closed before the end of the `transaction`. If the `handles` are not properly closed, the `delete` does not occur. All open handles to the file must be closed before performing the `commit` for the delete operation to be considered part of the transaction. This is because the system does not actually delete a file until the last handle to it is closed, even when the operation is not transacted, as part of the Windows file I/O subsystem.

#### Deleting a Directory

> A directory that is deleted by calling the `RemoveDirectoryTransacted` function **remains visible** to all outside readers.

#### Directory Locking Issues

> If a file is modified in a transaction, all directory components of the path to the file are referred to as **pinned against rename** until the transaction ends. That is, the system **prevents** you from **renaming** them until the transaction is committed or rolled back. An attempt to rename a directory that is an ancestor to a file that has been modified in an ongoing transaction will fail with the error **ERROR_CANT_BREAK_TRANSACTIONAL_DEPENDENCY.**

And here is some more info from [NTFS-3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#5):

#### Alternate Data Streams (ADS)

NTFS stores all data in streams. Every file has exactly one **unnamed data `stream`** and can have many named data `streams`. The size of a file is the size of its unnamed data `stream`. By default, `ntfs-3g` will only read the **unnamed data `stream`.** By using the options **“streams_interface=windows”** (not possible with lowntfs-3g), you will be able to read any named data streams, simply by specifying the stream’s name after a colon. For example:

```
cat some.mp3:artist
```

Named data streams act like normals files, so you can read from them, write to them and even delete them (using rm). You can list all the named data streams a file has by getting the “ntfs.streams.list” extended attribute.

#### And to set their use you use a module parameter:

```
streams_interface=value
```

This option controls how the user can access **Alternate Data Streams (ADS)** or in other words, `named data streams`. It can be set to, one of none, `windows` or `xattr`. If the option is set to none, the user will have no access to the named data streams. If it’s set to `windows` (not possible with `lowntfs-3g`), then the user can access them just like in Windows (eg. cat file:stream). If it’s set to `xattr`, then the named data streams are mapped to `xattrs` and user can be manipulated by using `{get,set}fattr utilities`. **The default is `xattr` on Linux,** none on other OSes.

We could get down and dirty with this I suppose. I think this could be related based on what I read above. Looking through their changelogs and I see:

> **`ntfs-3g`:** fixed returned files types in `readdir()`
>
> **`mkntfs:`** insert an `$Info stream` in `$UpCase` to comply with Windows 8
>
> **`ntfs-3g:`** keep the name of a `deleted file` in place for easier `undeletion`

All of the above look at least somewhat related to some of the *delete* issues mentioned in the `TNTFS` docs above.

Here's [what Tuxera NTFS-3G says](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#usedfreespace):

> Why doesn’t file deletion free disk space?
>
> In most cases it does, except for the following scenarios:
>
> > In some desktop configurations files are not deleted for real but moved into a `‘Trash’` or `‘.Trash-username’` directory in the root of the partition. When these directories are emptied then the disk space is reclaimed.
> >
> > By design, Linux and Unixes free the disk space of the deleted files permanently only if no software keeps them open anymore.
> >     `NTFS` is able to store small files and directories in fixed size `(1 kB) MFT` records (inodes). When such files are deleted then the `MFT` records are marked free for reuse or for undelete, and no space can be freed.

Status: **Not NTFS-3G problem.**

> Why can’t I move files to trash?
>
> > Moving a file to trash is only possible if the trash directory is owned by the current user. This implies that ownership of files has been enabled, either by forcing ownership to the current user or by using a generic ownership and permissions mode.

#### WIPING GETS MY VOTE

This doesn't look good short of wiping the disk - which might not be a bad idea. If you can access the files in Linux, just back them up. Then get the`exFAT` driver and use it - it is much simpler, and, well, to be honest I'm starting to wish it was the partition thing...

Or maybe it's ***fixed?***

> Why do I get an “Operation not supported” message when creating a file?
>
> > [The latest driver has solved this issue](http://www.tuxera.com/community/release-history/), please upgrade

#### OLD

This could be for a couple of reasons :

1. In Linux your `ntfs3g` driver can - as I think yours does - show the file **`streams.`** This is a little known and little used feature of the `NTFS` file system that is mostly used for the `shadow copies` kept by Windows itself to version files. Anyway, the result is that sometimes the *same file* is *two files.* Or more even.  This can get especially tedious if you delete files from an `ntfs3g` mount without properly handling Windows typed permissions on the disk. Effectively you will alter the *files' `streams`.* It's confusing, which is probably why it's not often used, but here you go: **[FILE STREAMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS)**
2. Your usb disk is **partitioned.** Windows does not handle well multi-partition disks marked with the *removable* flag - whereas that's all part and parcel to the Unix-way. There are options - **[Rufus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** and **[ImDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** are two I can think of off the top of my head.

I said *more likely* before for number two up there but looking closer at your question and I think number 1 is your problem.

#### DIGRESSION

I first learned about `NTFS` file `streams` when I built my first Windows installation image in Linux. Apparently much of what goes on during the Windows installation process is translating file `streams` in `.wim` archives into regular files during install. If you're at all interested in handling these in a Linux environment, I humbly recommend [`wimlib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I guess there's a ***third possibility,*** and maybe this is it after all:

> `3.` **[Missing, disappeared files or directories?](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)**
>
> If the top directory is completely empty then it’s very probably that the NTFS volume is not mounted. If only some files are missing then please upgrade to at least NTFS-3G 2009.1.1 which has full, built-in Unicode UTF-8 conversion support.
>
> If you use Mac OS X or FreeBSD and have at least one very long filename with national characters and the filename length translates into more than 255 UTF-8 bytes (higher chance with Korean and Greek languages) then Mac OS X and FreeBSD will not show any files in the directory.
>
> If you are double-booting with Windows 8, you may have enabled its fast restarting feature. This may cause Windows 8 to ignore changes done by another OS on any internal partition. A safe way to avoid loss of data is to disable the fast restarting by issuing as a Windows Administrator the command :

```
powercfg /h off
```

> If your computer has a SSD plugged in, it might be used by Windows as a cache controlled either by the hardware (“Intel Fast Response Technology”) or by software (“Expresscache”, “ReadyCache”, etc.). This feature is generally not compatible with both Windows and Linux and you may have to disable it.

[3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

Comment: Point #1 is not accurate. Windows does not use NTFS streams (aka Alternate Data Streams) on files to implement volume shadow copies. "delete files from an ntfs3g mount without properly handling Windows typed permissions on the disk" does not make sense - if you delete items, they're gone and their permissions are gone too.

Comment: And point #3 does not seem relevant - it's about files from Windows not appearing when an NTFS volume is mounted by the NTFS-3G driver, but the OP is having the opposite problem.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Are you sure about this - NTFS streams are not used for shadow copies? And if you permissions to delete them, you change a version. I'm going to look up the shadow copy - I might have it confused with xfs or xss or whatever that giant filesystem is in the windows directory - in which case I will appreciate the correction. Though it would be nice if you said what it was they were used for when issuing it.

Comment: @mikeserv: to my knowledge there are no unnamed streams in NTFS. The default data stream also has a name, even though you don't have to give the name to address it. Calling them **alternate** data streams is key to understanding it. For any other than the default stream, you need the name to address it.

Answer (score -1):

Just scan the drive in drive option.

You will get all of your data back which were gone that happens in NTFS file system though.